# Setting opacity of nodes with drop shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, shadows

How do I correctly set the opacity to semi-transparent (e.g., `opacity=0.2`) in a node with a drop shadow?
It seems that with the "naive" approach the shadow shows up through the semitransparent filling, which somehow makes sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [
                draw,
                fill=white,
                circle,
                blur shadow={
                    shadow blur steps=5
                },
                minimum size=1cm,
            ] at (0,0) {X};
            \node [
                draw,
                fill=white,
                circle,
                blur shadow={
                    shadow blur steps=5
                },
                minimum size=1cm,
                opacity=0.2,
            ] at (2,0) {X};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get a semi-transparent copy of the node of the left?

EDIT:

I already tried to set `draw opacity` and `text opacity` rather than just `opacity`, the result is somewhat better

[image]

but it seems that the shadow has full opacity now (since it's a `fill`, I guess), so it's still not 100% what I want.

Comment: aha, you have tried `draw opacity` and `text opacity` rather than just `opacity`, but for some magic reason, you forgot `fill opacity`, right? ^^

Comment: Was one of the answers helpful for you? If yes, consider voting or accepting or adding a comment about what is still missing.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a `transparency group` is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[cyan] (-1,-1) grid (3,1);
        \node [
            draw,
            fill=white,
            circle,
            blur shadow={
                shadow blur steps=5
            },
            minimum size=1cm,
        ] at (0,0) {X};
        \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
        \node [
            draw,
            fill=white,
            circle,
            blur shadow={
                shadow blur steps=5
            },
            minimum size=1cm,
        ] at (2,0) {X};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is already opacity in the proper way. Not sure what is your expected results. What is this use for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines,step=0.5cm] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\node [
font=\huge,
circle,
line width=3pt,
draw,
draw opacity=0.4,
fill=white,
fill opacity=0.7,
text opacity=0.4,
blur shadow={
shadow blur steps=5,
shadow blur radius=1.5ex,
},
minimum size=2cm,
] at (0,0) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried this but the shadow doesn't seem to be affected, i.e., it has full opacity. I will update my question.

Comment: @Filippo The default shadow opacity is 0.4. According to the document https://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-blur/pgf-blur.pdf, Check my new answer.

Comment: So actually the solution would be to set the `draw opacity` and `text opacity` to 0.2, and lower the `shadow opacity` to 20... This works only for white filled nodes, but it's something...